# Hide/Disable right click menu on firefox

Tags: firefox, web, mozilla

How to Disable the firefox menu when right clicked on the web page, firefox is dispalying a menu box which has options like 'Save Page As' , 'View Page Source' etc. I want to disable that menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Comment: This works on IE and chrome but not on firefox, I am looking for a solution in firefox